# Login Screen Issue: First lightdm needs to be killed to get X session to work

Tags: xorg, lightdm, login-screen, mate, amdgpu

I'm running MATE 20.04 and have a problem each time I reboot.  Instead of getting the lightdm login screen

1. When I have the grub option "silent" set I get a blank screen (it's all black but on)
2. When I remove the silent option, I get the following messages

   ```
   Loading, please wait..
   Starting version 245.4_ubuntu3.11
   Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
   Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount
   ```

   The screen goes blank and then redisplays the above messages

At this point, if I try to get to a local term (Ctl-Fn-F1), I have no luck.
However if I ssh into the machine and kill lightdm, the login screen appears.
Here's some more details

```
  > [machine ~] $ ps aux |grep lightdm
  > root        1173  0.0  0.0 232332  7484 ?        Ssl  14:45   0:00 /usr/sbin/lightdm
  > root        1225  0.2  0.6 1346752 67728 tty7    Ssl+ 14:45   0:00 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
  > user1       1854  0.0  0.0   9032   724 pts/0    S+   14:46   0:00 grep lightdm
  > [machine ~] $ sudo kill 1173
  > [sudo] password for user1:
  > [machine ~] $ ps aux |grep lightdm
  > root        1925  0.4  0.0 232332  7328 ?        Ssl  14:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/lightdm
  > root        1930 12.8  0.9 1497312 96312 tty7    Ssl+ 14:47   0:00 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
  > root        1955  0.2  0.0 159972  8236 ?        Sl   14:47   0:00 lightdm --session-child 17 20
  > lightdm     1959  5.0  0.0  18836  9948 ?        Ss   14:47   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
  > lightdm     1960  0.0  0.0 169680  4188 ?        S    14:47   0:00 (sd-pam)
  > lightdm     1969  4.0  0.1 358024 18308 ?        S<sl 14:47   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
  > lightdm     1972  0.0  0.0 166156  4764 ?        Sl   14:47   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
  > lightdm     1975  0.0  0.0   2608   540 ?        Ss   14:47   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/slick-greeter
  > lightdm     1976 25.2  0.4 601636 48404 ?        Sl   14:47   0:01 /usr/sbin/slick-greeter
  > lightdm     1977  0.5  0.0   7464  4608 ?        Ss   14:47   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
  > lightdm     1983  0.0  0.0 156092  5376 ?        Sl   14:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/dconf-service
  > lightdm     2011  0.0  0.0 305748  6592 ?        Sl   14:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher --launch-immediately
  > lightdm     2016  0.0  0.0   7332  4144 ?        S    14:47   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
  > lightdm     2017  0.0  0.0 239704  7512 ?        Ssl  14:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
  > lightdm     2022  0.0  0.0 312800  6144 ?        Sl   14:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/110/gvfs -f -o big_writes
  > root        2056  0.0  0.0  12560  6200 ?        S    14:47   0:00 lightdm --session-child 13 20
  > lightdm     2058  0.5  0.0 162828  7668 ?        Sl   14:47   0:00 /usr/libexec/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
  > user1       2064  0.0  0.0   9032   664 pts/0    S+   14:47   0:00 grep lightdm
```

Another 'fix' is to boot into safe mode then continue on via the 'resume' option.  The login shows up no problemo.

First, what's going on?

Second, why can't I access the terms via Ctl-Fn-F1?

Much obliged.

UPDATES:

- Using 'nomodeset' when booting the kernel avoids the problem.

  - This argument is also used in recovery mode and would explain why that method works
  - Unfortunately, I get a black screen when I resume from sleep if I use this 'solution'
- Getting notifications about not finding my external display

  - Tried booting with an external display plugged in and I get the login screen using the default settings (I don't need to use nomodeset)
  - Need to see if resume works next.
  - It seems like there's an issue with the login screen if I used an external monitor in the previous session.
    I suspect this means it's looking for the second display, can't find it and so it hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after many hours of rebooting, sshing in and restarting lightdm, then trying something else, I believe I have a solution!

There seem to be 2 issues with the solutions given here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LightDM

1. **Problem:** "LightDM service is started before your graphics drivers are properly loaded"

   **Solution:** Created `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-logind-check.conf` with the following lines

   ```
   [LightDM]
   logind-check-graphical=true
   ```
2. **Problem:** LightDM was trying to use the unattached external screen instead of the builtin screen.

   **Solution:** Forced it to use the primary screen at eDP by creating `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.d/lightdm.conf` with the line

   ```
   display-setup-script=xrandr --output eDP --primary
   ```